# Jenkins 1.5x to 2.6x Upgrade UI Layout Issue

Tags: user-interface, jenkins, jenkins-2

We have around 3000 jobs on a 3 year old Jenkins instance(1.564). As part of the upgrade, we are trying to move these jobs to Jenkins 2.60.1. I tried copying the jobs folder on the new instance. Everything looks good and works fine except the UI alignment in the job configure page. Its completely messed up. Please see attached.

[image]

Tried googling on the a fix. No luck. Anyone saw the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question but you may want to consider using a theme to upgrade the usability of Jenkins.

https://github.com/afonsof/jenkins-material-theme is a theme that you can either build and include in your jenkins or alternatively you can use their cdn and add to your external css listed in `https://your.jenkins/manage`

For reference, with the above theme installed, this is what a maven project looks like.
[image]

Comment: I will try this out and check whether this would fix the UI misalignment.